# Error while creating variadic class in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I am trying to create a class that when provided with a list of pairs of iterator begin and ends generates a sequence of vectors that give the cartesian product of the elements in the input vectors.

The code works when 2 pairs of iterators are given to the initializer of the class. However, when another pair is added, it fails to compile.

iterators.h

```cpp
template<typename InputIterator,typename ...InputIterators>
class Product{
    typedef  typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type base_value;
    InputIterator base,end,curr;
    Product* next = nullptr;
    void reset(){
        curr = base;
    }
public:
    explicit Product(InputIterator begin,InputIterator end,InputIterators... args) :base(begin),end(end){
        curr = begin;
        next = new Product(args...);
    }
    explicit Product(InputIterator begin,InputIterator end):base(begin),end(end){
        curr=begin;
    }
    bool has_next(){
        if (!next){
            return curr+1!=end;
        }
        return next->has_next() || (curr+1)!=end;
    }
    Product& operator++(){
        if (!next){
            curr++;
            return *this;
        }
        if(!next->has_next()){
            curr++;
            next->reset();
            return *this;
        }
        ++(*next);
        return *this;
    }

    std::vector<base_value> operator*(){
        if(!next){
            return std::vector<base_value>({*curr});
        }
        std::vector<base_value> ans = *(*next);
        ans.insert(ans.begin(),*curr);
        return ans;
    }



};
```

main.cpp

```
#include<vector>
#include"itertools.h"
int main(){
    std::vector<int> a = {0,1,2,3},b = {4,5,6};
    auto q = Product(a.begin(),a.end(),b.begin(),b.end());

    auto w =  *q;
    for(auto i:w){
        std::cout<<i<<' ';
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
while(q.has_next()) {
    ++q;
     w = *q;
    for (auto i:w) {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
}
    return 0;
}
```

**error**

```
In file included from main.cpp:4:
itertools.h:91:20: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Product<std::__1::__wrap_iter<int *>, std::__1::__wrap_iter<int *>, std::__1::__wrap_iter<int *>, std::__1::__wrap_iter<int *>, std::__1::__wrap_iter<int *> >'
        next = new Product(args...);
                   ^       ~~~~
main.cpp:11:14: note: in instantiation of member function 'Product<std::__1::__wrap_iter<int *>, std::__1::__wrap_iter<int *>, std::__1::__wrap_iter<int *>, std::__1::__wrap_iter<int *>, std::__1::__wrap_iter<int *> >::Product' requested here
    auto q = Product(a.begin(),a.end(),b.begin(),b.end(),b.begin(),b.end());
             ^
itertools.h:93:14: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 4 were provided
    explicit Product(InputIterator begin,InputIterator end):base(begin),end(end){
             ^
itertools.h:89:14: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 6 arguments, but 4 were provided
    explicit Product(InputIterator begin,InputIterator end,InputIterators... args) :base(begin),end(end){
             ^
itertools.h:81:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 4 were provided
class Product{
      ^
itertools.h:81:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 4 were provided
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a workup of 1201ProgramAlarm's answer (reduced to a minimal reproducible example).  I couldn't find a way to deduce `Product`'s template parameter.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

template <typename InputIterator>
class Product{
    InputIterator base, end,curr;
    Product* next = nullptr;

public:
    template <typename ... InputIterators>
    explicit Product (InputIterator begin, InputIterator end, InputIterators ... args) : base (begin), end (end){
        std::cout << "templated constructor\n";
        curr = begin;
        next = new Product (args...);
    }

    explicit Product (InputIterator begin, InputIterator end) : base (begin), end (end){
        std::cout << "untemplated constructor\n";
        curr=begin;
    }
};

int main(){
    std::vector<int> a = {0,1,2,3}, b = {4,5,6}, c = {7,8,9};
    auto q = Product <std::vector<int>::iterator> (a.begin (), a.end (), b.begin (), b.end (), c.begin (), c.end ());
}
```

Output:

```
templated constructor
templated constructor
untemplated constructor
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1u0tdQtLpunqqbqg)

Answer (score 1):

When you call `new Product` and pass it 6 iterators, your template class have 5 template parameters (the `InputIterator`, which is used by the first two parameters, and 4 other types in `InputIterators`).

In the constructor, you try to create a new `Product` but with two fewer parameters (4). The compiler finds constructors that take either 2 or 6 parameters (which it reports in the notes that go with the error). It cannot instantiate a 4 parameter constructor, because `InputIterators... args` is 4 (possibly different) types and needs 4 parameters.

One possible workaround would be to create a templated constructor that can essentially redefine what all the extra parameters are for.

Comment: while i understand what is wrong with the code, I do not understand why the call to `new Product` automatically invoke the variadic constructor rather than searching for a constructor with 4 parameters? Can you also explain a bit more about the work around?

Comment: @ParthVerma The line `next = new Product(args...);` searches for a constructor with 4 parameters, but the class doesn't have one. There's the variadic one (that in your failing test takes 6 parameters) or the "base case" constructor (that takes 2 parameters).

Comment: Again i still understand what is happening, but why is it recognising the variadic constructor as having 6 parameters as opposed to taking 2 parameters?

Comment: @ParthVerma Because you give it the first two, and the `InputIterators` pack expansion brings in another four.